# What does a newer Android API bring?

Tags: android, api

I have a question concerning Android APIs.

1) Does the latest API (in Android) include ALL features (classes) from the earlier ones?

2) Is there any features, that got removed by a newer API? If yes, is there any website showing me the added/edited/removed features?

thank you :)))))

Answer (score 2):

> Does the latest API (in Android) include ALL features (classes) from the earlier ones?

Generally, yes.

> Is there any features, that got removed by a newer API?

Sometimes, yes. Usually, what happens is that the resulting methods get marked as deprecated and do not do anything. Occasionally, stuff gets deleted from the class library outright.

> If yes, is there any website showing me the added/edited/removed features?

There is an API differences report for each API release. For example, [here is the report of the changes between API Level 20 and 21](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes.html).

Comment: The somewhat higher-level overviews (e.g. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html) can be a useful "big picture" summary, too.

Comment: Can I use all deprecated features?

Comment: @RoundAround: To the extent that they are still actually supported, yes. Some things that are deprecated do not do anything or return benign results (security stuff). Some things that are deprecated are Google's way of pointing you towards other solutions. Some things that are deprecated you *have* to use, as their replacements are not available on older devices. IOW, it varies.